# Using SQL Server in Cake PHP: PHP SQL Server interface is not installed

Tags: php, sql-server, cakephp

I inherited an old Cakephp site that was using adodb as a driver to connect to an MSSQL database and it turns out this is no longer supported in the new version of cake (1.3, we are in 1.2) so I'm trying to change the driver so I can upgrade. We're using IIS and a sql server 2005 database on a different server, php 5.2.17. However using driver "mssql" gives me the following errors:

PHP SQL Server interface is not installed. For troubleshooting information, see http://php.net/mssql/

Call to undefined function mssql_min_message_severity()

The top error leads me to a page regarding the old php_mssql.dll, which according to this question: ( [CakePHP: error when trying to use mssql datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921707/cakephp-error-when-trying-to-use-mssql-datasource) ) will become a problem when I switch to PHP 5.3 so I'm trying to use the php_sqlsrv*.dll for my php version but I still get the error. Could never get the mssql.dll one to work either. I do however see "sqlsrv support enable" in phpinfo.php and the whole sqlsrv section is intact there.

In cake php I'm using "driver => 'mssql'", is this the correct driver for the new sqlsrv dll? Is there something I'm missing? For kicks I tried 'driver' => 'sqlsrv', that fixes the php SQL Server interface error but I still get
"Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_min_message_severity() in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\riverstone-dev\www\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo\dbo_sqlsrv.php on line 107"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing the latest SQL Native Client set from Microsoft and reenabling the extension in PHP has worked, albeit on a different server. Please try the drivers below if having a similar problem:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=20098